# Radio buttons on form not rendering correctly after form validation failure- bootstrap

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

Rails 4 app with Bootstrap 3

I have a form that includes inputs from radio buttons:

```
<strong> Radio button options on form </strong><br>
   <div class="form-group">
     &nbsp<%= f.radio_button :category, 'A' %> &nbsp <%= f.label "A", "A" %><br /> 
     &nbsp<%= f.radio_button :category, 'B' %> &nbsp <%= f.label "B", "B" %><br />  
     &nbsp<%= f.radio_button :category, 'C' %> &nbsp <%= f.label "C", "C" %><br />
   </div>
```

The first time the form is loaded, everything looks correct:

[image]

My issue is that if the form fails due to a validation error (missing required input, etc, anywhere on the form), when the page re-renders, the radio button and the label are displaying on two different lines:

[image]

How do I fix this issue?

**Updated**
The generated HTML for each is:
Original (correct):

```
    <strong> Radio button options on form </strong><br>
    <div class="form-group">
      &nbsp<input id="listing_category_1" name="listing[category]" type="radio" value="1" /> &nbsp <label for="listing_1">A</label><br /> 
      &nbsp<input id="listing_category_2" name="listing[category]" type="radio" value="2" /> &nbsp <label for="listing_2">B</label><br />  
      &nbsp<input id="listing_category_3" name="listing[category]" type="radio" value="3" /> &nbsp <label for="listing_3">C</label><br />
    </div>
```

And for the re-rendering (incorrect):

```
    <strong> Radio button options on form </strong><br>
    <div class="form-group">
      &nbsp<div class="field_with_errors"><input id="listing_category_1" name="listing[category]" type="radio" value="1" /></div> &nbsp <label for="listing_1">A</label><br /> 
      &nbsp<div class="field_with_errors"><input id="listing_category_2" name="listing[category]" type="radio" value="2" /></div> &nbsp <label for="listing_2">B</label><br />  
      &nbsp<div class="field_with_errors"><input id="listing_category_3" name="listing[category]" type="radio" value="3" /></div> &nbsp <label for="listing_3">C</label><br />
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add the generated HTML and CSS, for both the original and the validated page?

Comment: Inspect with your browser's developer tools, figure out whether the markup or CSS has changed. We can't do this for you based on the above screenshot.

Comment: Thanks, updated with HTML

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `Rails` wrap fields with errors into a `div`:

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
  <input name="foo" type="radio" value="1" />
</div>
```

One way to solve could be customize this `css` class, for example making `div` display property `inline` instead of `block`:

```
.field_with_errors { display: inline; }
```

Another option, modify `Rails` setting to change default behaviour when displaying errors:

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| "<span class='field_with_errors'>#{html_tag}</span>".html_safe }
```

Comment: Adding .field_with_errors { display: inline; } to CSS worked like a charm.  Thanks!